# Azure diagnostic settings creation via powershell is not working

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, azure-diagnostics

I'm adding Diagnostic Settings via (Az) PowerShell to a LogicApp using the below powershell command, however, nothing is created in the diagnostic setting of the resource.

```
$LogicApp = "/subscriptions/dc4e35b0-3a98-41a6-86a0-e83de3d06b2e/resourceGroups/Lieblik/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/logic-lieblik-sitepoolingscheduler"

$Workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -Name "BO-Crayon-LAW" -ResourceGroupName "commonservices"

New-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $LogicApp -WorkspaceId $Workspace.ResourceId -Name "DiagMonitor"
```

OUtput shown is
[image]

I waited hours to check if it was due to some delay, but no luck!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the **`script`** which worked for me:

```
$RithResourceId = "/subscriptions/b83c84c23f/resourceGroups/vbojja/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/rith6"
$RithWorkspc = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -Name "rit54-workspacename" -ResourceGroupName "rgname"
$RithWkId= $RithWorkspc.ResourceId
$DiagnosticSettingName = "RithTesting"

$rithmetrics = New-AzDiagnosticSettingMetricSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category AllMetrics
New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $DiagnosticSettingName -ResourceId $RithResourceId -WorkspaceId $RithWkId -Metric $rithmetrics
```

$RithResourceId is the resource id of the resource where you want to create diagnostic setting.

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just added metric and log parameters to my script and it worked. Interestingly those are not mandatory parameters.

Comment: No, those are mandatory to create